# Java to a web service and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, web-services

I'm here to pose a kinda **noob question**, so please **no hate** here mates.

The java application I'm trying to create has the following structure.

```
                      login request via net                           Validation(same machine)
**JAVA PROGRAM** ---------------------------------> **WebService** ---------------------------------------> **db** 


          Response                       Response
**db** --------------> **WebService** ----------------> **JAVA PROGRAM**
```

But my doubt is on how to build that **webservice**.
I've watched several glassfish tutorials, but none of them seem to explain how to actually create this type of connections.

Thank you!

Comment: This question is way too broad to answer... In StackOverflow you are generally expected to demonstrate at least a minimal understanding of the problem domain and the basic skills of using Google. I don't think either of these criteria are met. If you've watched tutorials but didn't get anywhere, how do you expect us to suddenly make you realize everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should divide your problem into several sub-problems and then tackle them one by one. I'm not sure if I understood your setup correctly, but to me it seems like you need the following:

- Client Java application and the application logic
- Server Java application and the application logic
- Database
- Connection from the server application to the database
- Connection from the client Java application to the server application

In addition, you need to decide what kind of a connection you are going to use between your client and a server. Would it be a SOAP-based web service, a ReST service, plain HTML, just a simple POST/GET, or something else? Also, what kind of frameworks are you using? Spring, perhaps? Wicket? Something else?

Do you have any of those decided or done yet? Feel free to start a new question, I foresee this one being closed in the near future, because it's not clear what you are asking. Do study the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page. If you can show any code in your question, you are much more likely to get answers.

Anyway, to give at least some kind of an answer to your question, I'd use the [Spring Framework](http://spring.io/). Google for [spring sql tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=spring+sql+tutorial) and then either [spring restful web services tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=spring+restful+web+services+tutorial), [spring servlet tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=spring+servlet+tutorial) or [spring soap web service tutorial](https://www.google.com/search?q=spring+soap+web+service+tutorial) based on your technology of choice.

Comment: I didnt refer how I was going to make the connection because that was kind of my question xD But you just gave me a lot of new possibilities than the ones i had.

Answer (score -1):

Your database interaction will be same as normal does. You just need to broadcast your Validator class as a WebService.

Below links will help you to do so.

1. [For connecting java class with MySql](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm)
2. [For broadcasting your class as Webservice.](http://www.java2blog.com/2013/03/soap-web-service-example-in-java-using.html)

Comment: Please include relevant information from links in the answer itself. Answer are supposed to be self-contained and offer all the details required. Stack overflow is a question and answer site, not a question and "oh look over there" site, Google exists for that.